# Haskell not getting my functional dependency

Tags: haskell, constraints, typeclass, functional-dependencies

I am trying to create a queue type class that implements basic queue behavior. My code is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

data QueueA a = QueueA { front :: [a], rear :: [a] }

class Queue a b | a -> b where

  empty         :: a
  null          :: a -> Bool
  head          :: a -> Maybe b
  tail          :: a -> Maybe a
  toList        :: a -> [b]
  (|>)          :: a -> b -> a

instance Queue (QueueA a) where      

  empty = QueueA [] []

  null (QueueA [] []) = True
  null _ = False

  head (QueueA [] []) = Nothing
  head (QueueA (x:xs) _) = Just x

  tail (QueueA [] []) = Nothing
  tail (QueueA (x:xs) (y:ys)) = Just $ QueueA (xs ++ [y]) ys

  toList (QueueA x y) = x ++ y

  (|>) (QueueA x y) e = if (length x > length y) then QueueA (init $ e : x) ((last x) : y) else QueueA (e : x) y
```

Unfortunately, when I try to compile the code ghc tells me the following:

```
queue.hs:15:10: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Queue (QueueA a)’
      Expected a constraint,
        but ‘Queue (QueueA a)’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Queue (QueueA a)’
   |
15 | instance Queue (QueueA a) where 
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't really get the message though. All I know is that the pattern for the Queue in my instance declaration must be right, because it is exactly as I specified it in my data type above. I've tried several variations of my instance declaration, to no avail. Am I simply overlooking something? How do I make this compilable?

Comment: It seems clear enough to me: the `Queue` class expects two types, but you only gave it one, `QueueA a`. It's not totally clear to me what you're trying to do with this type and class, but it seems that `instance Queue (QueueA a) a` might work as you intend? (Actually, on further look I think I see more errors coming - but at least it will move you on.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple parameters for the class. Instead, the class should take a higher-order type as its argument, not a concrete type.

```
class Queue t where
    empty :: t a
    null :: t a -> Bool
    head :: t a -> Maybe a
    tail :: t a -> Maybe (t a)
    toList :: t a -> [a]
    (|>) :: t a -> a -> t a
```

`QueueA` itself has a `Queue` instance, not `QueueA a`.

```
instance Queue QueueA where
  -- same as above
```

Comment: Isn't the point of a typeclass like that so you can declare monomorphic instances of it, which this way doesn't let you do?

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking how to use a class to define the interface for an abstract data type, with each instance providing an implementation. For example, you can define a fairly trivial instance of `Queue` for `Data.Sequence.Seq` as well, not how to restrict a polymorphic container to a monomorphic one.

Comment: However, since a queue depends on its parameter only monomorphically (unlike, say, Functor), I think it should be strictly more flexible to declare it the original way with the fundep.  More cumbersome to use, however.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not clear on what "monomorphically dependent" means.

Comment: @chepner think `IsList` and the `mono-traversable` classes. In this case, the fundep way would let you build a queue out of `Text` or `ByteString`, but this way won't since those types can't contain arbitrary other types. (For this reason, in this particular case, the monomorphic way is less restrictive than the polymorphic way.)

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't see that as the goal of what the OP was trying to do, but it's certainly a reason to use a multiparameter class.

Answer (score 4):

Instances need the same number of parameters as the corresponding class. However, you created a class with 2 parameters and a corresponding instance with just 1. To make it compile, you can do `instance Queue (QueueA a) a where` instead of `instance Queue (QueueA a) where`. (You'll also need the `FlexibleInstances` extension.)

Comment: Well, in my class definition b should represent the type 'a' of Queue, so that in the class body I am able to specify the function (|>) and head's return value (which depends on the queue type).

Comment: So I hoped that QueueA would actually be recognized as type a of the typeclass Queue and the Constraint a as the Constraint b in the class. You proved my assumption wrong, can you please tell me how to do it right, too?